# PostgreSQL grouping with removing duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to select and group data based on category and date. The issue is that it is showing me duplicates of categories.

My query:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.date,
    NULL::uuid AS id_fruit,
    t.category, 
    t.good,
    t.not_good
FROM fruit_table t
join main_table mt on mt.id = t.id_fruit
WHERE t.date BETWEEN '2023-10-19' AND '2023-10-31'
    AND mt.main_id = '2089gh46'
    AND (t.category = ANY(ARRAY['apple', 'peach']) OR t.category IS NULL)
GROUP BY t.date, t.category,t.good,
    t.not_good;
```

Result:

| date | id_fruit | category | good | not_good |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2023-10-19" | null | "apple" | 1 | 0 |
| "2023-10-19" | null | "peach" | 2 | 0 |
| "2023-10-20" | null | "peach" | 1 | 0 |
| "2023-10-20" | null | "peach" | 3 | 0 |
| "2023-10-23" | null | "apple" | 2 | 0 |
| "2023-10-23" | null | "apple" | 5 | 0 |
| "2023-10-23" | null | "peach" | 3 | 0 |

I assume categories are duplicated because they are connected to `id`.
My task is to create a function taking `id_fruit` and returning categories for it. If I'm calling `main_id` it will display table with dates, distinct categories and counts (good and not_good).

What should I try so that my table will look like this:

| date | id_fruit | category | good | not_good |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2023-10-19" | null | "apple" | 1 | 0 |
| "2023-10-19" | null | "peach" | 2 | 0 |
| "2023-10-20" | null | "peach" | 4 | 0 |
| "2023-10-23" | null | "apple" | 7 | 0 |
| "2023-10-23" | null | "peach" | 3 | 0 |

`main_table` has `main_id` which is actually '2089gh46' (fruits) and '2089gh47' (veggie). Each `main_id` has many `id_fruit` in it, so I chose to join by `mt.id = t.id_fruit`. If I join on `main_id` the table looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue of duplicate categories in your result, you can modify your query to group the data by date, id_fruit, and category while summing up the 'good' and 'not_good' values for each group. This ensures that you get a consolidated view of your data.

Here is the refined query:

```
SELECT 
    t.date,
    t.id_fruit,
    t.category, 
    SUM(t.good) AS total_good,
    SUM(t.not_good) AS total_not_good
FROM fruit_table t
JOIN main_table mt ON mt.id = t.id_fruit
WHERE t.date BETWEEN '2023-10-19' AND '2023-10-31'
    AND mt.main_id = '2089gh46'
    AND (t.category = ANY(ARRAY['apple', 'peach']) OR t.category IS NULL)
GROUP BY t.date, t.id_fruit, t.category;
```